# React Navigation: problem navigating from within async function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, react-navigation

I have the following async function set up to delete a document in Firebase, and navigate to a specific screen once the delete action is complete:

```
const SensorHistoryScreen = (props) => {

  const { navigation } = props;

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const currentFarmId = useSelector((state) => state.session.currentFarm.farmId);
  const currentSensorId = useSelector((state) => state.session.currentSensor.sensorId);

  .......

  async function deleteSensor() {

    setLoading(true);

    await db
      .collection('farms')
      .doc(currentFarmId)
      .collection('sensors')
      .doc(currentSensorId)
      .delete();

    const afterDeleteNavigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'AppNavigator',
      action: NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'AccountList'
      })
    });

    props.navigation.dispatch(afterDeleteNavigateAction);

  }
```

The delete function works fine, but once it's done, I get an error:
`[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_native.NavigationActions.navigate')]`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says "evaluating '_native.NavigationActions.navigate'", so the issue is with the navigation, not firebase. You may wish to re-title your question so the right people can help you. Unless it works properly if you comment out the firebase code?

Comment: @jeffkmeng My mistake; half wrote the title and forgot to go back and finish it. I've updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Stack Navigators so my `afterDeleteNavigateAction` should look like this:

```
const afterDeleteNavigateAction = StackActions.replace('AccountList', {});
```

This navigates away correctly.